# variable gets assigned function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

My English = Google Translate. Sorry :(

```
function XXX(){
    abc = function(){return 'Message';}
    return abc;
}

function Alerttt(){
    var AlertText= XXX();
    alert(AlertText);
}
```

Result:

```
AlertText = function(){return 'Message';}
```

I want to:

```
AlertText = Message
```

How can I do?

Comment: Why are you defining nested functions at all? Can you modify `XXX`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```js
function XXX()
{
    abc = function(){return 'Message';}
    return abc;
}

function Alerttt()
{
    var AlertText = XXX()();
    alert(AlertText);
}

Alerttt();
```

Calling XXX returns a function object, so XXX() is a function object, and you need to call that function object as XXX()() to return 'Message'.

Comment: No. I want to AlertText = <Message>, not <function(){return 'Message';}>.

Comment: mKrgl: Please run and see. AlertText has the value 'Message' here.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to call the function.

```js
function XXX() {
  abc = function() {
    return 'Message';
  }
  return abc;
}

function Alerttt() {
  var AlertText = XXX();
  alert(AlertText()); // call it
}
Alerttt();
```

You can also do var `AlertText = XXX()();` so that `AlertText` gets the return value from the called function so you can `just do alert(AlertText);`

Comment: But AlertText is function(){return 'Message';}. I want to AlertText is'Message'.

Comment: That's `alert(AlertText());`, not `alert(AlertText);`.